# GeoJSON/GeoCouch questions from a newb

Tags: geojson

I am new to JSON and GeoJSON and would like to start to use this but I am a little confused about some things. Perhaps you can help me out:

1) Is there a GeoJSON validator out there?
2) Is the text below valid GeoJSON? To be a valid GeoJSON file do all the GeoJSON objects have to live in a GeoJSON array or can they be stored willie nellie as below?

The data below is a return from the [geocouch example on github](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch):

```
{
"rows": [
    {
        "id": "augsburg",
        "bbox": [
            10.898333,
            48.371667,
            10.898333,
            48.371667
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                10.898333,
                48.371667
            ]
        },
        "value": [
            "augsburg",
            [
                10.898333,
                48.371667
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "oakland",
        "bbox": [
            -122.270833,
            37.804444,
            -122.270833,
            37.804444
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -122.270833,
                37.804444
            ]
        },
        "value": [
            "oakland",
            [
                -122.270833,
                37.804444
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoJSON is also simply JSON, so I usually run it through the validator at http://jsonlint.com/ to check it passes this first. Unfortunately I don't think there is an online validator specific to GeoJSON.

You can however use the GDAL [GeoJSON driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_geojson.html) to try and load or get information about the dataset - if it fails it's invalid. You can also use the Python [Shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) library to check features as it uses a [GeoJSON-like notation](http://trac.gispython.org/lab/wiki/PythonGeoInterface) for geometry.

Your example seems to be missing some type attributes - features must have a type attribute and can be grouped in collections if needed. The key criteria for GeoJSON objects (from the spec) are:

> - GeoJSON always consists of a single object
> - The GeoJSON object may have any number of members (name/value pairs).
> - The GeoJSON object **must have a member with the name "type"**
> - The value of the type member **must** be one of: "Point", "MultiPoint",
>     "LineString", "MultiLineString",
>     "Polygon", "MultiPolygon",
>     "GeometryCollection", "Feature", or
>     "FeatureCollection". The case of the
>     type member values must be as shown
>     here.
> - A GeoJSON object may have an optional "crs" member, the value of
>     which must be a coordinate reference
>     system object
> - A GeoJSON object may have a "bbox" member, the value of which must be a
>     bounding box array

The GDAL driver also had [issues](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/gdal-dev-problem-with-gdalwarp-in-1-7-td5754766.html) if I did not set a `"crs"` value

For more details take a look at the full GeoJSON [specification](http://geojson.org/) and [examples](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#appendix-a-geometry-examples).

I also found the GeoJSON from CloudMade's services very useful for comparison - http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/geocoding/examples

Comment: GeoJSON validation will be problematic. Does a "geometry" property have to be paired with a "type:Feature" property? To be a GeoJSON Feature, yes. But do objects necessarily have to be contained within a GeoJSON FeatureCollection to be valid Features? I argue not. The object above (with "rows") isn't a Feature Collection but it does contain Features (or almost-Features).

Comment: @sgillies - well having one of the creators of the spec on this question certainly helps ;-) While you're here - according to the spec a CRS is not required correct? The GDAL driver seems to crash without it (in the last version I tested)

Comment: updated to state features need not be in feature collections and details from spec

Comment: [GeoJSON Lint](http://geojsonlint.com/) is an online validator of sorts. It should take care most of the worst.

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence because there is a big difference between `.geojson` and `.json` as `.geojson` contains coordinates which are stored in 1x2 or 1x3 arrays of numbers and their structure should be compatible with geometry type.

Comment: @ArashMad - all GeoJSON is valid JSON, but not all JSON is valid GeoJSON if that helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a validator but there is a spec (http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) you can consult.