# How to validate GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, validation

I have a small script that I'm using to generate GeoJSON data from a data format not currently supported by GIS software.

I would like to validate the output, but when I use ogr2ogr to read it, it doesn't give me any helpful information about what aspects, lines, or characters contained invalid data.

Is there a decent GeoJSON validator somewhere, or a good method of validating GeoJSON data with OGR?

EDIT: I am *not* looking for JSON validators or the GeoJSON spec. I've seen and used both to get to this point, but OGR still returns an error.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/geojson-geocouch-questions-from-a-newb

Answer (score 29, accepted):

5 months late, but I made this thing that should help http://geojsonlint.com/.

Comment: I use your service all the time.. However, the error ";Line 1: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule" should not occur.

Comment: This is no longer available.

Comment: @geocodezip Seems to be up and running as far as I tell, and working great!

Comment: does this have an npm library?

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer JavaScript there are now two options

- [GeoJSON-Validation](https://github.com/craveprogramminginc/GeoJSON-Validation)
- [geojsonhint](https://github.com/tmcw/geojsonhint)

Comment: both are down ...

Answer (score 2):

I have explained it before in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/22497/3071).

The differences between JSON and GeoJSON are all about spelling. You can add more definition if you want. I don't think it is very important if you do not take part in the JSON spec for GeoJSON... there is no limit for a JSON object; the only important thing is that your JSON must be valid for correct usage.

You can check whether or not your GeoJSON file is valid with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) which is a JSON Validator...

and you can check against the GeoJSON spec [here](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The GeoJSON spec is at [geojson.org](http://geojson.org/) - you linked to GeoJSON CSS, an unofficial extension.

Answer (score 2):

This [GeoJSON validator](https://www.itb.ec.europa.eu/json/geojson/upload) is extremely useful in parsing different types, but also helpfully points out exactly where the errors lie.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to reply to comments, but apparently enough to add an answer.  Go figure.  For the links that @null_radix provided, here are the corresponding npm links that should still be valid:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-validation
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/geojsonhint

The geojsonhint has been deprecated, but, as of the time of this comment, was still getting around 54K downloads per week, while geojson-validation was getting 15K.

Comment: FYI to anyone looking at these. They are for the old (deprecated) GeoJSON spec, not rfc7946.

Comment: @mapbox/geojsonhint is updated and current for the current spec.